# Getting files from subfolders in assets

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I got StreamProvider working with my application allowing me send images from my stamps subfolder inside assets. I was wondering about multiple subfolders in the assets directory.

I added a gifs folder from which i want to share gifs. This worked fine but when i wanted to send images from the stamps folder it would check the gifs folder instead, therefore saying the file was not found.

Is there a way to get different files from different subfolders in assets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <asset name="assets" path="stamps" />
    <asset name="assets" path="gifs" />

</paths>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to have separate names. The name is the first path segment in the `Uri`. You cannot have `content://your.authority.name.here/assets` point to two separate places.